# How can you map a set of numbers, full of "holes" into a smaller one without "holes"

Tags: math, set, mapping, transformation, space

Can anyone figure out a function that can perform a mapping from a finite set of N numbers X = {x0, x1, x2, ..., xN} where each x can be valued 0 to 999999999 and N < 999999999, to a set Y = {0, 1, 2, 3, ..., N}.

In my case, i have about 24000000 element in the first set whose values can range as X. This elements have continuous block (for example 53000 to 1234500, then 8000000 to 9000000 and so on) and i have to remap this elements from 0 to 2400000. I don't require to maintain order.

I need a (possibly simple and rapid) math function, or a bitwise transformation, not something like put it ordered into an array and then binary search for their position.

Really thank to whom that can figure out a way to solve this!
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to keep **some gigabytes** of straight map, then augmented segment tree is reasonable approach. Tree should contain intervals and shift of every interval (sum of left intervals). Of course, finding appropriate interval (and shift) in this method is close to the binary search.

For example, you get `X=80000015`. Find interval for this value - it is `8000000 to 9000000`. Rank of this interval is `175501` (`1234500-53000 + 1`). So X maps to

```
 X => 175501 + 80000015 - 80000000 = 175516
```

For sparse elements make counting stage - find what is rank R  for every number M and put `(key=M, value=R)` pair in hash table.

```
X = (3, 19, 20, 101)
table: [(3:0), (19:1), (20:2), (101:3)]
```

Note that one should keep balance between speed and space - for long filled intervals it is better to store only interval ends.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is much appreciated. I didn't know about [segment trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree). I can't find anything about **augmented** segment tree, could you provide some resource? However i can't get how this could help me to map uniquely elements from X to elements in Y

Comment: Augmented tree nodes contain some additional information - in this case rank - overall count of items in intervals left to given. Rank example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree  Example added

Comment: Let me benefit of your willingness: can you also figure out a way (no binary tree) to do the same thing if elements in X are sparse, without any contiguous section? I think that this is non-linear mapping, and i don't know which is the best way to discover it

Comment: Look at addition.